# Python: Is it unpythonic to have instance methods imported from different files?

Tags: python

When working on large projects, it is unpythonic to have instances methods for a class imported from different files? I am working on a large project were we are importing lots of functions as instance methods, and I want to know if it is good practice. So for a smaller example, we have two different files. One contains the main class, and the other has helper functions.

time_to_drive.py

```
class TimeToDrive:
    from helper_functions import calculate, check_variables, get_stats

    def __init__(self, avg_traffic_flow, length, speed, number_of_runs):
        self.avg_traffic_flow = avg_traffic_flow
        self.length = length
        self.speed = speed
        self.number_of_runs = number_of_runs

        self.check_variables()
        self.calculate()
        self.get_stats()
```

helper_functions.py

```
from random import random, uniform

import pandas as pd



def check_variables(self):
    if self.speed < 25 or self.speed > 80:
        raise Exception(f"Average speed limit of {self.speed}mph is not realistic")
    if self.avg_traffic_flow > 1 or self.avg_traffic_flow < 0:
        raise Exception(f"Average traffic flow must be between 0 and 1 (1 is best traffic, 0 is worst)")
    if self.length < 0:
        raise Exception(f"Length of route can not be less than zero")


def calculate(self):
    self.runs = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time needed', 'average speed'])

    for _ in range(self.number_of_runs):
        c = self.avg_traffic_flow
        x = random()
        exponent = uniform(1, 10)
        traffic_flow = c * x**(1/exponent) + (1-c) * x**exponent  # Function to calculate traffic flow
        speed = round(self.speed * traffic_flow, 2)
        time_needed_hours = self.length / self.speed
        self.runs = self.runs.append({'time needed': time_needed_hours, 'average speed': speed}, ignore_index=True)


def get_stats(self):

    self.avg_time = self.runs['time needed'].mean()
    self.avg_speed = self.runs['average speed'].mean()
```

And the imported function is able to modify self, and behave as normal instance methods. The code works fine, and if I were to run this in a separate file

```
from time_to_drive import TimeToDrive

if __name__ == "__main__":

    time = TimeToDrive(avg_traffic_flow=0.7, length=13, speed=50, number_of_runs=2)
    print(f'{time.avg_time} hours')
```

returns varies times that are needed to drive the route based on a function to calculate traffic flow. With an example output being

```
0.35 hours
```

I understand that for this particular example, importing the functions as instance methods do not make a lot of sense. It would be far more readable and pythonic to have the functions be apart of the class. But, is there something wrong with this approach? Because for very, very large projects, it gets messy importing a bunch of different functions from a bunch of different files. So writing code like this can reduce clutter and mess in the main class. Or is it always better to have something like this for this files?

```
from helper_functions import calculate, check_variables, get_stats


class TimeToDrive:

    def __init__(self, avg_traffic_flow, length, speed, number_of_runs):
        self.avg_traffic_flow = avg_traffic_flow
        self.length = length
        self.speed = speed
        self.number_of_runs = number_of_runs

        check_variables(self)
        self.runs = calculate(self)
        self.avg_time, self.avg_speed = get_stats(self)
```

```
from random import random, uniform

import pandas as pd


def check_variables(timetodrive):
    if timetodrive.speed < 25 or timetodrive.speed > 80:
        raise Exception(f"Average speed limit of {timetodrive.speed}mph is not realistic")
    if timetodrive.avg_traffic_flow > 1 or timetodrive.avg_traffic_flow < 0:
        raise Exception(f"Average traffic flow must be between 0 and 1 (1 is best traffic, 0 is worst)")
    if timetodrive.length < 0:
        raise Exception(f"Length of route can not be less than zero")


def calculate(timetodrive):
    runs = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time needed', 'average speed'])

    for _ in range(timetodrive.number_of_runs):
        c = timetodrive.avg_traffic_flow
        x = random()
        exponent = 4
        traffic_flow = c * x**(1/exponent) + (1-c) * x**exponent  # Function to calculate traffic flow
        speed = round(timetodrive.speed * traffic_flow, 2)
        time_needed_hours = round(timetodrive.length / speed, 2)
        runs = runs.append({'time needed': time_needed_hours, 'average speed': speed}, ignore_index=True)
    return runs

def get_stats(timetodrive):
    avg_time = timetodrive.runs['time needed'].mean()
    avg_speed = timetodrive.runs['average speed'].mean()
    return avg_time, avg_speed
```

Is there a place where community guidelines show best practices for this?
Any thoughts or opinions are welcomed

Comment: To me, this just decreases the clarity of the overall code. But this seems fundamentally opion-based to em.

Comment: Generally, segregating files into a module is meant to allow the module to be reused from multiple places. But methods that are specific to a particular class wouldn't usually be useful in other classes. There doesn't seem to be a logical reason to separate them.

Comment: [softwareengineering.se] might be a better place to ask a code organization question like this.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, I completely agree that this kind of question is opinion based by nature. But, I was wondering if something like this is generally okay to do

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the suggestion, I will go ahead and ask the same question at [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not Pythonic to have a regular function that acts as an instance method and modifies an instance's attributes.

For the purpose of deferring the implementation of some methods of a class to a different file, I would suggest that you make the main class an [abstract class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), and declare the helper methods needed by the constructor as abstract methods, so that you can implement those helper methods in a child class in a separate file.

For example:

**time_to_drive_base.py**

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class TimeToDriveBase(ABC):
    def __init__(self, length, speed):
        self.length = length
        self.speed = speed
        self.avg_time = None
        self.check_variables()
        self.calculate()

    @abstractmethod
    def check_variables(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def calculate(self):
        pass
```

**time_to_drive.py**

```
from time_to_drive_base import TimeToDriveBase

class TimeToDrive(TimeToDriveBase):
    def check_variables(self):
        assert self.length >= 0
        assert self.speed > 0

    def calculate(self):
        self.avg_time = self.length / self.speed
```

Comment: You see, I have a feeling that is what we are missing. We are not using child classes, and I believe a lot of our code would become a lot more organized using them

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on a large project were we are importing lots of functions as instance methods, and I want to know if it is good practice.

For large or small projects(although large projects start from small) you have to organise your code well.

- Design patters are key solutions for such problems.
  - Creational/behavioural/structural patterns

**Benefits**:

- Reusability
- Readability
- Pythonic and lot more.

Another approach - you can group helper function into one or many Util class.

Just a short example would be.

```
class MyMainClass:
    def __init__():
        self.utils = Utils()


class Utils:
    
    @staticmethod
    def my_helper():
         pass

    @staticmethod
    def my_another_helper():
         pass
```

Comment: a `Utils` class with a bunch of static methods shouldn't be a class at all, but just a regular module.

Comment: Correct that's why I have mentioned static/cls method. Again It depends on nature of project and lot many things. it's just an idea to avoid lot of functions for the way it is mentioned in question.